# How to change same images at multiple places using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know the solution that will help me change multiple same images using JS.

For example: There are 3 image tags below.

```
<img class="photo" src="myphoto.png">
<img class="photo" src="myphoto.png">
<img class="photo" src="myphoto.png">
```

And I want to change all the "myphoto.png" to "theirphoto.png" at once without change in every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of the elements with [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop over them to change each src.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img.photo').forEach(img => img.src = 'theirphoto.png');
```

Comment: thank you it worked. So same way can I change alt text too by replacing "=>img.src" to "=>img.alt" ?

Comment: @Frankie Yes, you can. To change multiple attributes, you will need to wrap the body of the arrow function with `{}`, e.g. `img => {img.src = 'src'; img.alt = 'alt';}`